# How to add two colors to a text from a table in react native?

Tags: react-native

I work to an app and I use react native. I have a table into a dropdown and I want to have different colors of the text, anyone know how can I do this?
For exemple, in "random text" , "text" I want to have another color.[View the design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLG6z.jpg)

The code:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Table, Cell, Row, Rows } from 'react-native-table-component';
import { colors } from '../Themes/Colors';

export default class ExampleOne extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      tableHead: ['Random text'],
      tableData: [
        ['PRET REDUS', ' TVA inclus'],
        ['REDUS: 30 ']

      ],
    }
  }

  render() {
    const state = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 3, borderColor: colors.yellow}}>
          <Row data={state.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.text}/>
          <Rows data={state.tableData} textStyle={styles.text}/>
        </Table>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding:10, paddingTop: -10 ,margin: 6, marginLeft:30},
  head: { height: 40 },
  text: { margin: 6, color:colors.yellow }
});
```

Comment: You want your table header text be in different color? Then Add another style


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: { flex: 1, padding:10, paddingTop: -10 ,margin: 6, marginLeft:30},
  head: { height: 40 },
  text: { margin: 6, color:colors.yellow },
  textHead: { margin: 6, color:colors.red },
});


and use it like this


<Row data={state.tableHead} style={styles.head} textStyle={styles.textHead}/>

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer at this on this page right at the bottom : https://github.com/Gil2015/react-native-table-component

Where you can change the style with:

```
const elementButton = (value) => (
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => this._alertIndex(value)}>
        <View style={styles.btn}>
          <Text style={styles.btnText}>button</Text>
        </View>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    );

    this.state = {
      tableTitle: ['Title', 'Title2', 'Title3', 'Title4'],
      tableData: [
        [elementButton('1'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],
        [elementButton('2'), '1', '2', '3', '4'],
        [elementButton('3'), 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
      ]
    }
  }
```